# Operator overloading in R reference classes

Tags: r, operator-overloading, reference-class

I'm relatively new at OOP and need advice: What is the best way to overload the Arithmetic generic operators in reference classes in R?

For example, suppose I define

```
bar <- setRefClass( "foo", fields=list(a="numeric", b="numeric" ))
```

If I try the obvious thing:

```
> bar$new(a=3,b=1) + bar$new(a=1,b=3)  
Error in bar$new(a = 3, b = 1) + bar$new(a = 1, b = 3) :  
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What is the recommended way to do something like (a+a) + (b+b)?

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what you wanted to do, but look: `rab <- bar$new(a=3,b=1) ; class(rab) ; rab$a ` will point out a couple problems.  You'll need to define a `+` method which tears apart your objects and puts them back together.  Unless you have a strict need to interact with an OOP language, I'd recommend avoiding `RefClass`es and using the standard `R` classes and methods.

Comment: I am working with massive datasets, so using standard R with its pseudo copy-by-value methods causes memory headaches.  Reference classes are extremely helpful for this problem, and I find them extremely helpful. When combined with data.table, I can replicate many of the facilities in sqldf and ff with very little effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that reference classes are S4 + environments, and define an S4 method:

```
bar <- setRefClass("foo", fields = list(a = "numeric", b = "numeric"))
one <- bar$new(a = 1, b = 1)
two <- bar$new(a = 2, b = 2)

# Find the formals for + with getGeneric("+")
setMethod("+", c("foo", "foo"), function(e1, e2) {
  bar$new(a = e1$a + e2$a, b = e1$b + e2$b)
})
one + two
```

It's similarly easy to define a set of methods for a group generic:

```
setMethod("Ops", c("foo", "foo"), function(e1, e2) {
  bar$new(a = callGeneric(e1$a, e2$a), b = callGeneric(e1$b, e2$b))
})
one / two
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried a variant of that setMethod command, but I didn't do it properly. Can this answer be generalized to all the arithmetic primitives?

Comment: @AndrewZachary example added